# Approximation for a correlation matrix

Tags: time-series, correlation, approximation, fourier-transform

I have a cross-correlation matrix of some parameter for each time period. E.g. expected economy growth for each months in the future, i.e. growth for Apr 2014, May 2014, ...., Dec 2018, and correlation(Apr 2014, Aug 2015) etc. From history I can obtain empirical this correlation table. It will have seasonal periodicity, e.g. correlation between Dec 2018 is high with Dec 2017, but low with June 2018. Is it possible to create an approximating function to this empirical correlation table that is a function of time, i.e. F(Year_month_1, Year_month_2) so that I can take it and extrapolate into the future and produce the future correlation matrix. This function should preserve the positive definiteness.

The key here is the preservation of positive definiteness, so it cannot be simply polynomial-Fourier type of expansion. They will give good functional approximation but will break the matrix being a correlation matrix.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CrossValidated! Your question is not clear as to what you want to extrapolate. What I understand is that you have one parameter, and a correlation matrix of each month-year with each other month-year. What seems implied is that you want to expand the matrix size, say, from a $n \times n$ matrix to a $m \times m$ matrix where $m > n$.

What I don't understand is why you don't just use an auto-correlation function of the growth as a function of time, which seems simpler and easier to work with. Can you clarify that what you want is the above, and why an auto-correlation through ti

Comment: Maybe my choice of growth as an example was misleading. Consider the price of electricity for each year-month. So June 14 and Aug 14 are two different processes, i.e. paths on themselves with some correlation. You are correct, i want to extend matrix for extrapolation.

Comment: So if you have a correlation between June 14 and August 14, then the price of electricity for each is in some way a random variable, and not just an observation? Or what data do you use for those correlations?

Comment: Yes, for each month it is a random variable in itself. We have historical data what these random variables were for each month in future. E.g. we have all this history from 2010 - 2014 June for June 14 prices futures prices.